# Async callback from auth0 lock getting lost if triggered after 10 seconds in a react-native app

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have some odd behavior in my react-native app where the callback trigger is never firing if I don't trigger the callback within about 10 seconds.

I'm programmatically triggering the auth0 react-native-lock login modal in the root component and looking for it's callback.  If I submit the auth0 lock within about 10 seconds the callback triggers and it works as intended.  However, if I don't submit the login within 10 seconds, the lock screen completes as normal but the callback in the login never gets triggered.

If instead of calling login from the root, and I instead trigger it from a button press in the App component, it works fine and I can take longer than 10 seconds to trigger the callback.

Why does the async callback disappear or not get triggered if I call the login action from the root container?

```
// root.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

import App from './App';
import { client } from './client';
import { login } from './actions';
import reducers from './reducers';

reducers.apollo = client.reducer();

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers(reducers),
  {},
  compose(
      applyMiddleware(client.middleware()),
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
  ),
);

export default class Root extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(login());
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client} store={store}>
        <App />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

And my action that's losing the callback

```
// actions.js

export function login() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    lock.show(null, (err, profile, token) => {
      // sometimes this callback never fires if 
      // the login window is open for more than 10 sec.
      // then dispatch authenticated actions
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem, just turn off the debugger and try again. Everything works fine.

Comment: disabled live debugging in react native - but that didn't change anything..